# How to remove products tab when it has no value in admin in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, products

I am using Magento 2.3

I have set custom product tabs in product detail page

Now I want to display a particular product tab only if it contains a value in admin. for ex. if there is no description for a particular product in admin then I want to hide description tab from detail page and same should be for other tabs as well.

> app/design/frontend/My_vendor/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml

```
<?php

<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <div class="product info detailed">

        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                    <div class="product-attachment" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $html ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I think I have to make changes in the above file. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have not mentioned how you have added the custom tab. Let's say you have used this tutorial to add custom product tabs on the product detail page.

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-tab-product-page-magento-2/

We have

> **[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="test.tab" template="[Vendor]_[Module]::custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

So right now your custom tab will show even if your custom attribute value is empty.

**To disable tab for empty attribute value**

> **[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
        <observer name="remove_block" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\RemoveBlockCustomTab" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> **[Vendor]/[Module]/Observer/RemoveBlockCustomTab.php**

```
    <?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RemoveBlockCustomTab implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    )
    {        
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') {
            $product = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
            //$attrVal = $product->getAttributeText('test');
            $attrVal = $product->getData('test');
            if(!isset($attrVal) || trim($attrVal) === ''){
                $layout = $observer->getLayout();
                $layout->unsetElement('test.tab');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have created product attribute with code `test` to check.

In above file

`->getData('test');` here `test` is my custom attribute code.

`'test.tab'` is the name of our block from `catalog_product_view.xml`.

Tested in Magento 2.3.0. I hope it helps

Comment: @Chintan Kaneriya I have made a mistake when I posted the answer. You will need to check the `if` product page in observer. Answer is updated now.